# Using a value as a field name in a QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, expression

Regarding SQL expressions in QGIS:

Based on the value of the field `"_majority"`, I want to subtract the value of the field with the corresponding name from the field `"_count"`.

Using the image below as an example, as the value in `"_majority"` is 5, I want to select field `"5"` and subtract the corresponding value of 25177 from the `"_count"` field.

[image]

Is this possible using an expression in QGIS's Field Calculator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a little tricky but doable, since you cannot turn the content of a field into a fieldname. But you can use maps as a workaround:

```
map_get(attributes($currentfeature), "_majority")
```

This will first turn your current feature into a map of keys (fieldnames) and values (fieldvalues). Here you can use the value of `"_majority"` to get the value of the corresponding key by using [`map_get()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#map-get).

So your final expression will be `"_count" - map_get(attributes($currentfeature), "_majority")`

Answer (score 5):

You can get the target field name using `"majority"`, and then you can evaluate ([`eval()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#eval)) the value of the record at this field. To make is a field name and not a simple string (or number here), one would concatenate (`||`) double quotes around it.

`eval('"'|| "majority" ||'"')`

or for the whole expression

`"_count" - eval('"'|| "majority" ||'"')`